# Autolayout for FLAnimatedImageView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I'm using FLAnimatedImageView to integrate GIFs into my app using the GIPHY API. I had added autolayout constraints for leading, trailing, top, bottom, and height. However, for some reason, the image ends up being larger than my height constraint (image below). How should I fix this?

[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7BGp.png)

[new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BoAt.png)

Comment: Can you add your constraints, please?

Comment: Don't use the height constraint with the top and bottom setted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIView` has a `contentMode` property. `FLAnimatedImageView` inherits from `UIImageView`, which inherits from `UIView` so you can use `contentMode` in `FLAnimatedImageView` as well.

Set `contentMode` to `.scaleAspectFit` and it should resize the image to fit the image view without modifying the aspect ratio.